# What's the semantic of a data structure(abstract data structure) which has order(with index) but doesn't allow duplicates?

Tags: data-structures

For example, if a data structure has order(has index) and allows duplicates, the semantic is [List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)). If a data structure has no order and doesn't allow duplicates, the semantic  is [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)). If a data structure has no order but allows duplicates, it's [Multiset or Bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

What's the terminology of an abstract data structure which has order(has index) but doesn't allow dupicates?

Comment: List - but with your variation built on it. maplemapleList?

Comment: RBTrees (or BSTs) have order (not direct indexing) and do not allow duplicates.

Comment: @lllrnr101 LOL . One implementatiton is similiar to LinkedHashSet. However, I don't know the name of this kind of interface.